# Modify naive search algo to allow tollerance

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, search

I'm trying to mod the following naive search function, to find sequences that are in a range of tollerance (each digit can be +/- X%).

this is where I start:

```
Public Shared Function searchX(ByVal haystack As Byte(), ByVal needle As Byte())
        Dim M As Integer = needle.Length
        Dim N As Integer = haystack.Length

        For i As Integer = 0 To N - M
            Dim j As Integer

            For j = 0 To M - 1
                If haystack(i + j) <> needle(j) Then Exit For
            Next

            If j = M Then
                Return i
            End If
        Next
    End Function
```

So, if I correctly understand how the Naive algo work, the comparation of the pattern with my array is done in the line  `If haystack(i + j) <> needle(j) Then Exit For`.
So I change it like that:

'code deleted as asked from my team that own it

I tested it with different array and patterns, but now it  look like it can ony find a sequence of "0"; What am I missing? Is my understand of this algo totally wrong?
UPDATE:
I put some data to minimal testing:

```
Dim haystack = New Byte() {&H0, &H1, &H2, &H3, &H4, &H5, &H6, &H7, &H8, &H9, &HA, &HB, &HC, &HD, &HE, &HF, &H1, &HF1, &HF4, &H3F, &H24, &HF4, &HF2, &HF4, &HF2, &H4F, &H2F, &H4F, &H2F, &H43, &HF2, &H4F, &H2F, &H4F, &H23, &H4F, &H23, &HF4, &HFF, &H42, &HF4, &HF3, &HF4, &H32, &HF4, &HF3, &H2F, &H4F, &H23, &HF0}
        Dim haystack2 = New Byte() {&H0, &H1, &H2, &H3, &H4, &H5, &H6, &H7, &H8, &H9, &HC, &HD, &HE, &HD, &HE, &HF, &H1, &HF1, &HF4, &H3F, &H24, &HF4, &HF2, &HF4, &HF2, &H4F, &H2F, &H4F, &H2F, &H43, &HF2, &H4F, &H2F, &H4F, &H23, &H4F, &H23, &HF4, &HFF, &H42, &HF4, &HF3, &HF4, &H32, &HF4, &HF3, &H2F, &H4F, &H23, &HF0}
        Dim needle = New Byte() {&HA, &HB, &HC}
        Dim tollerance = 20
```

Using the needle A,B,C in the first haystack and tolerance=0 I should get the match at position 10, and none in the hatstack2. Then with tollerance = 20 I should find a match in both haystack at the same position 10 because the needle's values still in the 20% of tollerance.

Comment: The `>` and `<` symbols are *operators* - they don't work like you expect from mathematics.  (a < b) is a function that returns a value (ie: true or false).  If you chain them like `if a < b < c` you evaluate the first one first, which then reduces to `if (true) < c`, which is nonsensical.  Suggest you work through some basic tutorials to learn the language first - before you start jumping into algorithms.  Each comparison needs to stand alone, ie : `if (a<b) and (b<c)`

Comment: Also, do yourself a favour and turn on [`Option Strict`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) in the project options.  If you do that at least this gives you a warning : `Error BC30512 Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Boolean' to 'Double'`

Comment: Done, but the function still not find anything.

Comment: Functions need a return type. If you turned on Option Strict you would have edited you code in your question to reflect this. You have not declared err in your sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comments on the For loops.

```
Private haystack As Byte()  = New Byte(){&H0, &H1, &H2, &H3, &H4, &H5, &H6, &H7, &H8, &H9, &HA, &HB, &HC, &HD, &HE, &HF, &H1, &HF1, &HF4, &H3F, &H24, &HF4, &HF2, &HF4, &HF2, &H4F, &H2F, &H4F, &H2F, &H43, &HF2, &H4F, &H2F, &H4F, &H23, &H4F, &H23, &HF4, &HFF, &H42, &HF4, &HF3, &HF4, &H32, &HF4, &HF3, &H2F, &H4F, &H23, &HF0}
Private needle As Byte() = New Byte() {&HA, &HB, &HC}
Private haystack2 As Byte() = New Byte() {&H0, &H1, &H2, &H3, &H4, &H5, &H6, &H7, &H8, &H9, &HC, &HD, &HE, &HD, &HE, &HF, &H1, &HF1, &HF4, &H3F, &H24, &HF4, &HF2, &HF4, &HF2, &H4F, &H2F, &H4F, &H2F, &H43, &HF2, &H4F, &H2F, &H4F, &H23, &H4F, &H23, &HF4, &HFF, &H42, &HF4, &HF3, &HF4, &H32, &HF4, &HF3, &H2F, &H4F, &H23, &HF0}
Public Shared Function searchXWithT(ByVal haystack As Byte(), ByVal needle As Byte(), ByVal err As Byte) As Integer
    Dim M As Integer = needle.Length
    Dim N As Integer = haystack.Length
    For i As Integer = 0 To N - M 'For i = 0 To 10
        For j = 0 To M - 1 'For j = 0 To 2
            If (CDbl(needle(j) - (needle(j) / 100 * err)) < CDbl(haystack(i + j))) And (CDbl(haystack(i + j)) < CDbl((needle(j) / 100 * err) + needle(j))) Then
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If j = M Then 'M will always be 3 and j can never be more than 2
            Return i 'i will never be returned
        End If
    Next
    Return 0
End Function
```